# Round Off Error? - Java

Tags: java, rounding, multiplication

Ok, so i made a scientific calculator recently and one of my friends was using it when he said that if he types in (2.1 * 3) the answer should be 6.3 but he recieves something like: 6.30000001.

Why does this happen?
Is this some sort of bug in java?

EDIT: Its not just a problem with my calc, i also made a small java file for multiplying 2 numbers and i face the same probelem even in cmd

Comment: See this answer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/588014/3440545

Comment: http://powerfield-software.com/?p=30

Comment: question about floating point precision has been asked thousands times here.

Comment: It's a bug in base 2 floating point representation.